# How to String-Integer signed value to 2 byte array on the Davik VM? 

Tags: java, android, dalvik

Given a integer value from a string, I want to convert it to 2 byte signed integer.

`BigInteger` does the job, but I don't know how to grant 2 bytes...

```
public void handleThisStringValue(String x, String y){
  BigInteger bi_x = new BigInteger(x, 10);          
  BigInteger bi_y = new BigInteger(y, 10);
  byte[] byteX = bi_x.toByteArray();
  byte[] byteY = bi_y.toByteArray();
}
```

I noticed that `BigInteger.toByteArray()` handles negative values which is suitable for me.

Then I need to read those values (negative and positive ones), or saying convert `byte[2]` to `signed int`. Any suggestion?

Comment: What's wrong with `Integer.parseInt()`?

Comment: I need to covert a signed int to byte[] and then back to signed int.
Integer.parseInt() converts String to int.

Comment: I see, based on your code I assumed you were converting a string into an int in a long way thorugh byte[]s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, based in posts I found here (thank you for all):

Remember that I wanted a 2 byte integer... so it is a Short!

```
String val= "-32";
short x = Short.parseShort(val);
byte[] byteX = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(x).array();
```

... and it works!

Then, I'm using BigInteger to read it back!

```
int x1 = new BigInteger(byteX).intValue();
```

or

```
short x2 = new BigInteger(x).shortValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, your questions still lacks certain information.

First, Java integers are 32-bit long, so they will not fit into a 2-byte array, you need a 4-byte array, otherwise you are actually dealing with short data type, which is 16-bit long.

Also, not sure if you need to deal with any kind of byte ordering (little endian, big endian).

At any rate, assuming that you are using integers that only fit in 16-bits and big endian byte ordering, you could do something as follows to create the byte array:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(String number){
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.putInt(Integer.parseInt(number));
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer.array(), 2, 4); //asumming big endian
}
```

And as follows to convert it back:

```
public static int toInteger(byte[] payload){
    byte[] data = new byte[4];
    System.arraycopy(payload, 0, data, 2, 2);
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getInt(); 
}
```

You can also change the byte order of the ByteBuffer with the `ByteBuffer.order` method.

I used it as follows:

```
byte[] payload = toByteArray("255");
int number = toInteger(payload);
System.out.println(number);
```

Output is `255`

Comment: Unfortunatly I dont have copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to)  method in my Array class. I'm developping for Android :(

Comment: @Jorge Use System.arrayCopy instead, then, as I did in the other method.

Comment: Why not use Short.parseShort() and ByteBuffer.putShort() instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
int x = bs[0] | ((int)bs[1] << 8);
if (x >= 0x8000) x -= 0x10000;
// Reverse
bs[0] = (byte)(x & 0xFF);
bs[1] = (byte)((x >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: This seems to be byte[2] to int. And the inverse? int to byte[2]?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the inverse:

```
new BigInteger(byteX);
new BigInteger(byteY);
```

It's exactly what you want, and then you can use `.intvalue()` to get it as an `int`